# create and fill new column with date condition between a range pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I want to create a new column that will hold the week number in the month ie (week 1, week 2 etc...)

I created a date range for each weeks and used if condition to fill the new columns but it doesnt work I keep getting errors

```
week1 = df[(df['start_time'] >= '2019-02-01') & (df['start_time'] <= '2019-02-07')]
week2 = df[(df['start_time'] >= '2019-02-08') & (df['start_time'] <= '2019-02-14')]
week3 = df[(df['start_time'] >= '2019-02-15') & (df['start_time'] <= '2019-02-21')]
week4 = df[(df['start_time'] >= '2019-02-22') & (df['start_time'] <= '2019-02-28')]

if df['start_time'] == week1:
    df['trip_week'] = 'Week 1'
    
elif df['start_time'] == week2:
    df['trip_week'] = 'Week 2'
    
elif df['start_time'] == week3:
    df['trip_week'] = 'Week 3'
    
else:
    df['trip_week'] = 'Week 4'
```

| start_time |
| --- |
| 2019-02-02 |
| 2019-02-11 |
| 2019-02-22 |
| 2019-02-03 |
| 2019-02-27 |
| 2019-02-14 |
| 2019-02-17 |
| 2019-02-08 |
| 2019-02-14 |

Expected Output

| start_time | trip_week |
| --- | --- |
| 2019-02-02 | Week 1 |
| 2019-02-11 | Week 2 |
| 2019-02-22 | Week 4 |
| 2019-02-03 | Week 1 |
| 2019-02-27 | Week 4 |
| 2019-02-14 | Week 2 |
| 2019-02-17 | Week 3 |
| 2019-02-08 | Week 2 |
| 2019-02-14 | Week 2 |

Comment: Use `np.where`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work:

```
df["trip_week"] = "Week " + ((df["start_time"].dt.day // 7) + 1).astype(str)
```

Adds a column with `"Week "` followed by the integer of the week (dividing the day of the month by 7 - floor division - and adding 1).